# JQuery append closing div tag only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a "universal wrapper" for several different external sites that would build a nav and footer with jquery and xml.

My problem: Since the script will be used on multiple sites that were built by other people, I need to build a container out just inside the opening and closing body tags.  I have been able to target the body to prepend `<div id="wrapper">`, but I need to close the div somehow and trying to append only `</div>` does not work.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").append("</div>");
});
```

My question: Is there a way to render `</div>` on its own?

Comment: I'm having a small problem with wrapInner.  When I use the code
("body").wrapInner("<div id='wrap'></div>");
I get this:

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN">
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<DIV id="wrap">
<DIV id="wrap" jQuery1245627494453="2">
</DIV>
</DIV>
</BODY></HTML>


Any idea why it is spitting out twice?

Comment: What does your initial markup look like, without running the wrap-inner?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/navigation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>

Comment: Place your script tags within your <head> tags. I just tried this and it worked. I also tried with my script tags in the bottom of my <body> tag, and it created two wrappers, as you experienced as well.

Comment: genius!  Thanks much for your patience and determination! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you looked at [.wrapInner()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapInner)? It will allow you to wrap all of the contents of `<body></body>` with a starting and ending tag:

```
$("body").wrapInner("<div id='wrapper'></div>");
```

That will result in:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- original markup here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

**Caution**: One thing I noticed was the fact that jQuery will create the wrapper twice if the script is ran from within the body tags.

Answer (score 2):

could you not use

```
$("body").wrapInner("<div id='wrap'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapInner

Might be what you're looking for.